# With virt-manager can I save a guest then reboot the host

Tags: virt-manager

I see `virt-manager` can make snapshots if qcow2 is used. I also see a "save" button.

Suppose I want to save a machine, is it ok to do save and maybe at reboot (of host, not guest) I can resume the machine?

Or I have to make a snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *managed save* option of `virt-manager` pauses the guest and dumps its memory (and CPU state) to a save file. The corresponding *start* reloads the guest so that it can continue on from where it left off.

This works with Linux-based guests but I can say that empirically it does not work with Windows-based guests (they don't successfully restart).

```
virsh managedsave {guest}
...
virsh start {guest}
```